# Android Studio. How do you restore Palette items?

Tags: android, palette

This is what my palette looks like now:

[image: CapturedImage]

Comment: If I think what your saying is this, I believe you have something typed into the search bar. See this image for more details. http://prntscr.com/ih1b77

Comment: Well, just look at the picture, and you will see. No need to look for hidden message

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. All i'm saying is that you have unknowingly put something in the search bar, ctherefore Android Studio is only showing any containing your searched words. Simply remove the text that I highlighted in my previous comment and all should be fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've typed something into the search bar which is filtering the results. Click the clear button next to the search bar. [image: clear button]